# Solve $\int_{0}^{1}y(xt)dt=ny(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration

Solve $\int_{0}^{1}y(xt)dt=ny(x)$

Could someone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Try doing a change of variable of $z = xt$ then taking a derivative of both sides.

Comment: Clear and concise.  +1

Answer (score 2):

Substituting $r=xt$, implies that:
$$ny(x)=\int_0^1y(xt)dt=\int_0^x\frac{y(r)}{x}dr=\frac{1}{x}\int_0^xy(r)dr,$$
which means that $nxy(x) = \int_0^xy(r)dr$.
Now take the derivative (with respect to $x$) from both sides, it gives you:
$nxy'(x) + ny(x)= y(x)$, which is equivalent to $nx\frac{dy}{dx}=(1-n)y(x)$ and then:
$$\frac{dy}{(1-n)y}=\frac{dx}{nx}.$$
Taking integral from both sides gives you $\ln y = \frac{1-n}{n} \ln x$, and finally:
$$y = \exp\left(\frac{1-n}{n} \ln x\right).$$

Comment: I see that you are new to the site! This is a great answer. This is a very low quality question as there was no good faith shown by the OP (by showing work done). There is a rough understanding that with such low quality questions, we should not provide full answers. Often such questions are homework questions and we try hard not to simply be a homework answering service. You can of course leave your answer as-is, but in the future, try to give hints rather than full solutions when faced with such a low effort post.

Comment: $y=Ax^{-(1-1/n)}$ for any $A$ works as a solution.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thanks for your advise. I will put it in effect for sure.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
ny'(x)&=\int_0^1 ty'(xt)\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^1\left(\frac1x \frac{d}{dt}(ty(xt))-y(xt)\right)\,dt\\\\
&=\frac1x y(x)-ny(x)\\\\
&=(1-n)\frac1x y(x) \tag 1
\end{align}$$

for which $(1)$ is a linear first-order ordinary differential (separable) equation.